# Simulate REST API for specific error response codes and statuses in Spring Boot

Tags: rest, spring-boot, testing

I am trying to simulate specific REST endpoints to return specific response codes and messages in QA environment so that the application consuming the services can be tested for different response scenarios.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Where are these _simulated_ endpoints located? If inside your Sprint-Boot app, you can mock (=simulate responses) _Controllers_ using e.g. Mockito. External endpoints are mocked with e.g. WireMock.